# Restricting auto Help Page contents when using Attribute Routing in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, attributerouting, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I'm currently implementing a Web API using Web API 2's attribute routing (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). I am also using the Help Pages module in order to automatically generate documentation from XML comments (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages).

For this API I am providing support for optional return format extensions, so that every API method has a pair of routes defined on it like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Path/Foo")]
[Route("Path/Foo.{ext}")]
public HttpResponseMessage DoFoo()
{
    // Some API function.
}
```

This allows a user to hit any of these and get a result:

```
www.example.com/api/Controller/Path/Foo 
www.example.com/api/Controller/Path/Foo.json
www.example.com/api/Controller/Path/Foo.xml
```

My issue is that when Help Pages uses MapHttpAttributeRoutes() to generate documentation, it is picking up both routes for each method. So right now I see help for:

```
api/Controller/Foo
api/Controller/Foo.{ext}
```

But I want to only see:

```
api/Controller/Foo.{ext}
```

I would prefer to hide the non-extension route on each method, so that every method only shows a single Help Page entry.

Has anyone else tried something similar? Is there a work around that I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My question would be is that, would consumers of your api figure out easily that the `{ext}` is optional?...personally, I would prefer the default behavior...but anyways following are some workarounds that I can think of:

1. A quick and dirty workaround. Split the DoFoo into 2 actions like DoFoo() and DoFooWithExt maybe. Notice that I am using an attribute called `ApiExplorerSettings`, which is for HelpPage purposes. Example below:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("Path/Foo")]
   [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)]
   public HttpResponseMessage DoFoo()
   {
       return DoFooHelper();
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("Path/Foo.{ext}")]
   public HttpResponseMessage DoFooWithExt()
   {
       return DoFooHelper();
   }

   private HttpResponseMessage DoFooHelper()
   {
       //do something
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom `ApiExplorer` (which HelpPage feature uses internally) and check for specific routes like the following and can decide whether to show the action or not for that particular route.

   ```
   // update the config with this custom implementation
   config.Services.Replace(typeof(IApiExplorer), new CustomApiExplorer(config));

   public class CustomApiExplorer : ApiExplorer
   {
       public CustomApiExplorer(HttpConfiguration config) : base(config)
       {

       }

       public override bool ShouldExploreAction(string actionVariableValue, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IHttpRoute route)
       {
           if (route.RouteTemplate.EndsWith("Path/Foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           {
               return false;
           }

           return base.ShouldExploreAction(actionVariableValue, actionDescriptor, route);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Get list of all `ApiDescription` from the default `ApiExplorer` and then filter out the descriptions which you do not like. Example: 
   `Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions.Where((apiDesc) => !apiDesc.RelativePath.EndsWith("Path/Foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: Thanks for all of these options. Perhaps hiding the versions with the .{ext} would be clearer. Either way, I don't want both routes to be visible for every method since it's very cluttersome. I also want to avoid option #1, but both #2 and #3 look promising. I'll be back with an update later.

Comment: The #2 option, overriding ApiExplorer, works great. The customization is clearly understood and since I'm already injecting a custom TraceWriter via the same config.Services.Replace call, it matches my current code.